# How to get string from add_theme_support('title-tag') for meta tag and beautify?

Tags: meta-value, wp-title

It recommends that we should use `add_theme_support('title-tag')` for displaying blog title. However, I also need to get the title as string for another purpose. It's for optimizing SEO. As you already know, some service like OG or Twitter has their own title meta tag like:

```
<meta property='og:title' content='need to be filled in'/>
<meta property='twitter:title' content='need to be filled in'/>
```

And the problem is I don't have a good way to query a title string to fill in the content. Also, another problem is I want to customize title format, like setting blog's name position or using a different separator.

So, do you guy have anyway to query a title string that can:

- be used to add to meta tags?
- be modified its format?

Comment: See [`wp_get_document_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/) which you can use to get the document title, and for changing the title parts, see [`document_title_separator`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/) and [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/).

Comment: I see, I can just replace the result of `wp_get_document_title()` with the pattern `' -  '` right. Btw, could you post the answer so I could close the question please?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. And yes, basically. But if you're trying to change the document title separator (which defaults to `-`/hypen), then you should use the `document_title_separator` hook as in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have a good way to query a title string to fill in the content

You can use [`wp_get_document_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_document_title/) to get the document title.

So for example in your case: (see [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) for details on `esc_attr()`)

```php
<?php
// Put the title (string) in a variable.
$title_esc = esc_attr( wp_get_document_title() );
?>
<meta property='og:title' content='<?php echo $title_esc; ?>'/>
<meta property='twitter:title' content='<?php echo $title_esc; ?>'/>
```

> I want to customize title format, like setting blog's name position

You can do that via the [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) hook.

But first, the document title has the following parts by default, and they're passed as an array to callbacks hooked to `document_title_parts`:

```
| Part                                | Array key | Optional | Position |
|-------------------------------------|-----------|----------|----------|
| Title of the viewed page.           | title     | No       | 1        |
| Page number if paginated.           | page      | Yes      | 2        |
| Site description when on home page. | tagline   | Yes      | 3        |
| Site title when not on home page.   | site      | Yes      | 4        |
```

The "optional" state means that the array item **may or may not exist** on certain pages — e.g. on page 1 of a category archive, the `page` item doesn't exist (or is excluded) by default, but on page 2 and above, `page` is included.

So for example, if you want the blog/site title to be the first instead of the default last:

```php
function my_document_title_parts( $title ) {
    if ( isset( $title['site'] ) ) {
        $site = $title['site'];  // get
        unset( $title['site'] ); // unset
        // Then put it at the top.
        $title = array_merge( [ 'site' => $site ], $title );
    }
    // Remember to return an array.
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'my_document_title_parts' );
```

And based on the above code, here are some sample output of `var_dump( $title )`:

```
// Home page.
array (
  'title' => 'My Site',
  'tagline' => 'Just another cool WordPress site',
)

// Category page 2.
array (
  'title' => 'Uncategorized',
  'page' => 'Page 2',
  'site' => 'My Site',
)

// Single Post.
array (
  'title' => 'Markup: HTML Tags and Formatting',
  'site' => 'My Site',
)
```

> or using a different separator

You can do that via the [`document_title_separator`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/) hook.

Here's an example for using `|` than the default `-` (i.e. a hypen):

```php
function my_document_title_separator( $sep ) {
    return '|';
}
add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'my_document_title_separator' );
```

### Notes

- Changing the title parts via `document_title_parts` or the title separator via `document_title_separator` will also change the title parts/separator which WordPress use in the `title` tag. There are solutions such as using a closure, but I'm not giving any examples for that (for now).

Comment: I've tested your solution and I can confirm it works beautifully. With your way, we can even put emoji to the title. Thank you very much for your detail answer.

Comment: You're welcome. :) And just to clarify, the `var_dump()` sample output in the answer is for the title (`$title`) before the blog/site title is re-positioned.